# React Native M1 Mac build failure with target "React-Codegen"

Tags: ruby, xcode, react-native, cocoa, apple-m1

When I run the command `npx react-native run-ios` in my terminal on my Mac I receive the error

```
CompileC /Users/jessicageorge-mannella/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-ctnixtnnzajiwuhfvbyaxlajljew/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.o /Users/jessicageorge-mannella/Documents/testing/AwesomeProject/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'React-Codegen' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

I'm running react native 0.71.5, ruby version 2.6.10, cocoapods version 1.11.3, node version 18.15.0, Xcode version 14.3 and I tried even re-installing MacOS on my laptop in attempt to delete broken version installs. Here's the full list of my installed packages in relation to react-native as-well as some system information

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.3
    CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
    Memory: 150.44 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.15.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 9.6.3 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.03.27.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.4, iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
    Xcode: 14.3/14E222b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: Not Found
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
    react-native: 0.71.5 => 0.71.5
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you installed pods under Rosetta or with a command prefix ?

Comment: I have RN 0.71.4 with ruby 2.7.6 and I can run my commands without Rosetta with success. I installed ruby with ruby-install and chruby as version manager

Comment: From RN 0.71.5 there is no more committed .ruby-version as you can see in the changelog but the doc still mention that 2.7.6 is required for this version. I'm not sure that this cause the issue but I would recommend to install a ruby version manager. From my experience this one is the less buggy:  https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [a known issue with react-native that was reported on March 31st](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36739) in the react-native GitHub repository. It is related to incompatibility between Xcode 14.3 and react-native versions prior to v0.71.6.

[v.0.71.6](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.71.6) has been released that [resolves the issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/0010c3807d7e47d7d518667dbfac62f7c0da1ac1) by changing the minimum targeted iOS version to 12.4. Prior to this version being released there was a [suggested patch](https://github.com/travis-mark/lrn/commit/015854716feadd61a904d5a603b027426472f863) that could be applied to v0.71.5.

And for older versions of react-native (e.g., v0.70.6) [a different suggested patch](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/36759#issuecomment-1493710771) may be applied instead.

Answer (score 9):

**Quick Fix:**
Go to `Pods` -> Select `React-Codegen` from `Build Settings` and update `iOS Deployment Target` to `iOS 12.4`.

[image: pods build settings]

**Stable Fix:** Refer
https://github.com/travis-mark/lrn/commit/015854716feadd61a904d5a603b027426472f863

Comment: what are the drawbacks using this quick fix instead of upgrading RN?

Comment: Bless you bless you a million times

Comment: Anything above 12.+ will work

Answer (score 0):

This can simply be solved by changing the minimum ios version of ReactCodegen inside Xcode targets to 12.0 or greater.

I was facing this issue and I got out of it with this fix.